# MVC & Google Line Chart: Data plotted does not start at 0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I have a google line chart and the problem is, it does not start at 0 on the x-axis. I've seen this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516519/google-line-chart-starting-coordinate), but the solution seems to work only if x-values are numeric. Mine are not, unfortunatly.

[image]

**Does anbody know how to resolve this?** Maybe it's a problem related to the way I fill the chart with data, this is how I add the columns and rows:

```
               tdata.addColumn('string', data[0][0]);
               for (var i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
                   tdata.addColumn('number', data[0][i]);
               }

               tdata.addRows(data.length);
               for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
                   tdata.setCell(i, 0, data[i][0]);
                   for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                       var value = parseInt(data[i][j]);
                       tdata.setCell(i, j, value);
                   }
               }
```

And the data I feed to this is in this format:

```
{ "", "Kasse", "Anleihen", "Fonds", "Futures", "Optionen", "Aktien" } [Column names]
{ "01.02.2012", "10", "12", "23", "10", "12", "23" }
```

Comment: It looks like your first column (which becomes the x-axis) is of type 'string' and the rest are 'number'.  What would it mean to have 0 on the x-axis for a string?

Comment: hm i dont understand why but the first row ( = first x-point & values) consisted of null values only. i remove row(0) and the chart looks fine now. I dont get why it consists of nulls only because the input has no empty row.

Comment: I bet the first null row has to do with starting your loops at 1.  You should start at 0 (i.e. i=0 and j=0), since JS arrays are 0-based.